# Django Forms Not adding objects to DB

Tags: python, html, django, forms

My View function to handle the form looks like this ==>

```
def login(request):

 form=Login()
 if request.method=="POST":
     form=Login(request.POST)#populate
     if form.is_valid():
        Username=forms.cleaned_data['Username']
        Password=request.cleaned_data['Password']
        TPerson=Person.objects.create(Username=Username,Password=Password)
        TPerson.save()
     else:
         form=Login()      
 context={
      "Login":form,
  }
 return render(request,"photos/login.html",context)
```

and My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <body>
    <form action="/photos/memes.html" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <div  style="padding-bottom: 10px;" > <span>{{Login}}</span></div>

       <br/>
         <input  type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</body>
```

And here is my Urls.py=>

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .models import Memes

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.index,name="index"),
    url(r'^memes',views.memesPage,name="memes_home"),
    url(r'^0',views.PageRedirect,name="redirect"),
    url(r'^'+str(Memes.objects.count()+1),views.PageMoreRedirect,name="more_red$"),
    url(r'^(?P<meme_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail,name="meme_detail"),
    url(r'^login',views.login,name="login")
]
```

whenever I click submit the object is not being uploaded to the database.The page redirects and everything

Comment: IT works but i dont understand

Comment: In order to understand (which this example is one of the simplest ones) you must read some of the Django docs, or better, please, do complete the Django tutorial (link is in my answer).

Comment: Also, because it did work for you, mark it as accepted. That's a good practice in StackOverflow!

Comment: no i meant what did i do wrong when i redirected the page to the /memes.html

Comment: What you did wrong was several things. That's the truth. 1st the `action="/memes.html` was wrong. `action` excepts a url, not a HTML file. 2nd in your `views` you didn't handle the form's POST data correctly. If you follow the django tutorial, you'll understand a lot of the Django's workflow!

Comment: when i use {% url 'index' %} in the action it does not work?

Comment: This is because the `view.index()` function is not able to handle your form data. The `action` determines *the view fuction that will handle the data*. So, you tell it "hey, `index` view function, please handle these form data". But the `index` view is not written to handle these, in contrast to the `login` one.

Comment: Ok, Can you tell  me how do i find the username from another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATE 2]**: Change your `views.py` to this:

```
def login(request):
    form = Login()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Login(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['Username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['Password']
            TPerson = Person.objects.create(Username=username, Password=password)
    return render(request, 'photos/login.html', {'Login': form})
```

Then in your `photos/login.html` add these inside the `<form>` and check any errors:

```
<form action={% url 'login' %} method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
   <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;" >
       {% if Login.errors %}
           The errors are: <span>{{ Login.errors }}</span>
       {% endif %}
       <span>{{ Login }}</span>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**[UPDATE]**: Change this `<form action="/photos/memes.html" method="POST">` to this `<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">`.

You should better follow and complete the excellent [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/). It will be good for you!

Several things happen in your code:

1. `Username=forms.cleaned_data['Username']` should be `....=form.cleaned_data['Username']`. Not `forms`.
2. You are getting the password from the `request` object, instead of the form. So, it should be like this: `Password=form.cleaned_data['Password']`
3. There is no need to call `TPerson.save()`. The `create()` function will automatically save the object to database for you.

Comment: Last thing I can thought of is the url `/photos/memes.html`. Does it actually exist? Could you please share your `urls.py`?

Comment: You just posted your **old and false** `views.py`. You should edit your initial question for edits like that. Please edit your question and add your `urls.py` file.

Comment: sorry i am a bit of a noob

Comment: No worries. Updated my answer. You should also read @Todor answer below. He highlights some good practices for clean, pythonic code ;)

Comment: Username=forms.cleaned_data['Username'] should be ....=form.cleaned_data['Username']. Not forms. isnt it

Answer (score 0):

The form is presumably not valid. But in that case you create a new form instance, so you never show any validation errors. Remove that `else` clause and the template will show the errors.